# Snapshot command not producing high-res image

Tags: qgis, export, windows-7, 64bit

I'm trying to export an image of my project with a size of several hundred megapixels (32768x16384) via the snapshot command and all I get is an output file with 0 KB and no error message. I can export 16384x8192 just fine, but apparently 32768x16384 is too much.

I have 8 GB RAM but according to perfmon.exe QGIS doesn't even use half that when attempting to export the image. A 32768x16384x24 bitmap is still only 1.5 GB in size anyway.

Trying to narrow down the issue I also noticed that there is some other weird stuff going on when exporting images with very large dimensions. I exported the same narrow horizontal strip of a world map both in 16834x1024 and in 65536x4096, and in the larger image everything east of the prime meridian is just missing:

- [16834x1024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDfv.png)
- [65536x4096](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3yx.png)

The images above use the [global GADM database](http://www.gadm.org/version2) with a Miller projection (EPSG:53003).

Possibly related to this is a similar issue I have where all raster images (e.g. from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/)) are [cut off east of Okinawa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5XZ9.png). This happens regardless of resolution, but only with some projections. For example, it happens with EPSG:53003 (Sphere_Miller_Cylindrical), EPSG:54003 (World_Miller_Cylindrical), EPSG:54004 (World_Mercator) and EPSG:3395 (WGS 84 / World Mercator) but not with EPSG:4326 (WGS 84).

Edit: I still have these issues with QGIS 2.14.3 Essen and now 24GB RAM; can someone please try to reproduce them on 64-bit Win 7?

Comment: You may reach the 32 bit operating system file size limit. Do you use the command line --snapshop command line option or the composer export to image?

Comment: --snapshop command, and also 64-bit OS (otherwise I wouldn't have 8 GB RAM).

Comment: I got bad alloc error for 32768x16384 image: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'` after several errors from X . Probably there is a limitation in X if you use Linux.

Comment: I added some tags to make it clear that I'm using 64-bit Win7. Probably should have done that from the start.

Comment: Just to clarify. We understand you are using 64 bit windows. But are you also using the 64 bit install of QGIS?

Comment: According to Process Explorer qgis-bin.exe is 64-bit.